# Does ITIL fit into an Agile world?

Tags: agile, agile-processes, itil

Our IT manager is pushing for ITIL, I'm only loosely familiar with it and wanted to know if ITIL fits into an Agile work-cycle well?

From my initial impression I would assume no, mainly because what our manager is proposing is to put timelines against everything, stating SLA's to the business that "high priority tasks must be completed in x hours" etc... which we get penalised as developers if we do not meet these SLA's.

If anything I'd prefer a negotiation strategy where timelines are based on agile methods of velocity and story points to negotiate an expected timeframe to end users.

We have our agile development practices in place, test driven development, continuous integration, there's areas for improvement but we're working on it.

What are others experiences with ITIL and Agile methods working together?

Comment: Your question is on topic on the [ITIL Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89073/itil?referrer=x5X3k7r_NAmvg4ZTdjTOlw2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my company ITIL framework is used for service delivery (production and incident support). For this SLAs are appropriate as if you are say losing customers/money per hour then it is expected that business should have some indication of when things will be fixed. It is not directly related to development methodology. Only if you decide that an emergency hotfix is required and approved then some development may be done. But hotfixes are usually very small and targeted to fix a defect and shouldn't cause any issues with agile methodology. New requirements are never done as hotfix change and are taken in normal dev/test/release process.

Comment: So would you say that normal development processes can be exempt from ITIL methodologies and have ITIL purely concentrate on the infrastructure/incident support areas?

Comment: Well incident can also be software related. E.g. in a complex enterprise environment may be some application doesn't work due ti bad data. Or a batch job that should kick in automatically fails because the previous job aborted etc. Supporting all this may require data fix or a config file or schedule change etc. Very rarely you may find a real defect and that needs to fixes right away as an emergency code change and release. ITIL should take care of that.

Comment: Yes normal project development is not under ITIL and can follow agile processes. There is no SLA for projects as projects are generally a longer term effort than fixing an incident and projects have plans including release plans.

Comment: Thanks for the update and sorry for the delay. This is exactly how the apps team feel, however the IT manager still tries to put SLAs around us by applying the same SLA rules globally. For example, one SLA is we must fix a medium priority issue within half a day of it being reported, however bugs and new feature requests are treated equally so when I don't deliver new feature requests in half a day I'm penalized. I think it's time for a new job :)

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look good at all, if that's the case, it really doesn't fit agile at all.

I'm suspicious if ITIL really calls for that, specially since "high priority tasks must be completed in x hours" goes beyond not fitting agile, it doesn't fit software development i.e. all tasks aren't born equal.

**update:**

> So would you say that normal development processes can be exempt from ITIL methodologies and have ITIL purely concentrate on the infrastructure/incident support areas?

I don't think this is mutually exclusive. While it might be the case that ITIL isn't applicable in how you manage the team, it doesn't mean there aren't valid areas of it that affect what you develop.

Development needs to include considerations in the design/product that are required by infraestructure / support, and such may relate to practices suggested in ITIL.

**Maybe a more appropriate question would be: are management aspects/practices of ITIL applicable to management of software development?** which I don't know, but suspect is addressed specially in ITIL. At least I know that ITIL 3 introduced changes that relate to Enterprise Architecture practices, that are definitely compatible with agile (in fact are enablers) --- but at least those are far from anything related to fixed estimations / task tracking / dev response times.

Comment: I tend to agree, our manager was a part of the infrastructure/support team and is trying to apply the same rules for software tasks and support requests. Trying to explain that doesn't seem to go down well.

Comment: @Brett I suggest you find references that go beyond agile. Trying to apply the nature of infraestructure/support to development is a different beast altogether, it goes both ways - skills don't transfer the same / people in each side tend to miss a lot of critical bits of the other.